# Is it possible to read excel file from azure storage file system using SSIS-IR running in azure data factory?

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory

I have excel file in azure storage file system. Also running SSIS-IR in adfv2. Is it possible to read excel file from file system using SSIS-IR ? Trying to read excel file and insert into sql db.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using Copy Activity in ADF,please refer to the [Supported data stores  table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats) of it.

Configure source as [Azure Storage File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-file-storage) and sink as [SQL DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server).

Comment: I don't think excel is supported in Copy Activity. I know i can use both SSIS and ADF if the file format is CSV. Can you explain further how to work with excel in copy activity?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to load excel files using SSIS-IR, you need to install the required drivers on the SSIS runtime following the process here => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-configure-azure-ssis-ir-custom-setup

Keep in mind SSIS-IR is expensive, you are also able to load the file with a custom azure function.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I didn't see exact script require in main.cmd to install the required drivers. I added SAS URI to SSIS-IR but what should be included in main.cmd?

Comment: Did you look at the examples available in the blob storage her => https://ssisazurefileshare.blob.core.windows.net/publicpreview?sp=rl&st=2018-04-08T14%3A10%3A00Z&se=2020-04-10T14%3A10%3A00Z&sv=2017-04-17&sig=mFxBSnaYoIlMmWfxu9iMlgKIvydn85moOnOch6%2F%2BheE%3D&sr=c ? You have exactly what you are looking for in the CustomSetupScript/UserScenarios/EXCEL/ folder, cmd included.

Comment: Yes I did, may be I am confused. How do I get to CustomSetupScript/UserScenarios/EXCEL/ folder? When I restart SSIS-IR with SAS URI it didn't give me any folders

Comment: You need to connect to the blob storage https://ssisazurefileshare.blob.core.windows.net/publicpreview?sp=rl&st=2018-04-08T14%3A10%3A00Z&se=2020-04-10T14%3A10%3A00Z&sv=2017-04-17&sig=mFxBSnaYoIlMmWfxu9iMlgKIvydn85moOnOch6%2F%2BheE%3D&sr=c with azure storage explorer. You will be able to see the folder then.

Comment: Sorry but i tried and connected successfully didn't see that folder. Still I am not sure what to include in main.cmd. I left it blank hoping it will create these folders